# Not parsing correctly nested xml tags in python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I'm working with XML files in python. I have a dataset containing sentences in several languages, and is structured like this:

```xml
<corpus>
  <sentence id="0">
    <text lang="de">...</text>
    <text lang="en">...</text>
    <text lang="fr">...</text>
    <!-- Other languages -->
    <annotations>
      <annotation lang="de">...</annotation>
      <annotation lang="en">...</annotation>
      <annotation lang="fr">...</annotation>
      <!-- Other languages -->
    </annotations>
  </sentence>
  <sentence id="1">
    <!-- Other sentence -->
  </sentence>
  <!-- Other sentences -->
</corpus>
```

What i want to get is, starting from the dataset, a new dataset containing only the sentences and the annotations in english ("en" value of the attribute "lang"). I tried this solution:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('samplefile2.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for sentence in root:
  if sentence.tag == 'sentence':
    for txt in sentence:
      if txt.tag == 'text':
        if txt.attrib['lang'] != 'en':
          sentence.remove(txt)
      if txt.tag == 'annotations':
        for annotation in txt:
          if annotation.attrib['lang'] != 'en':
            txt.remove(annotation)
tree.write('output.xml')
```

But it seems to work only on the level of the `text` attribute, not on the level of the `annotation` attribute. I tried even replacing in the python side of the solution elements like `sentence, txt, annotation` with incremental indexes `root[s], root[s][t], root[s][t][a]`, but it sorts no effect. Furthermore, the python code i provided inserts randomly in the xml file (honestly i don't know if this could be helpfull to solve this issue) strings like `&#948;&#951;&#956;&#953;&#959;&#965;&#961;&#947;&#943;&#945;`.

So, I strongly believe that the problem is in the nested tags, but I can't figure it out. Some ideas?

Comment: Are you able to use lxml instead of ElementTree? I think this would be much easier using xpath.

Comment: I didn't consider that, i'm going to try!

Comment: I'll go ahead and add an lxml answer; in case you need an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to use lxml, I think this would be easier using xpath...

**XML Input** (input.xml)

```xml
<corpus>
  <sentence id="0">
    <text lang="de">...</text>
    <text lang="en">...</text>
    <text lang="fr">...</text>
    <!-- Other languages -->
    <annotations>
      <annotation lang="de">...</annotation>
      <annotation lang="en">...</annotation>
      <annotation lang="fr">...</annotation>
      <!-- Other languages -->
    </annotations>
  </sentence>
  <sentence id="1">
    <!-- Other sentence -->
  </sentence>
  <!-- Other sentences -->
</corpus>
```

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree

target_lang = "en"

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

# Match any element that has a child that has a lang attribute with a value other than
# target_lang. We need this element so we can remove the child from it.
for parent in tree.xpath(f".//*[*[@lang != '{target_lang}']]"):
    # Match the children that have a lang attribute with a value other than target_lang.
    for child in parent.xpath(f"*[@lang != '{target_lang}']"):
        # Remove the child from the parent.
        parent.remove(child)

tree.write("output.xml")
```

**XML Output** (output.xml)

```xml
<corpus>
  <sentence id="0">
    <text lang="en">...</text>
    <!-- Other languages -->
    <annotations>
      <annotation lang="en">...</annotation>
      <!-- Other languages -->
    </annotations>
  </sentence>
  <sentence id="1">
    <!-- Other sentence -->
  </sentence>
  <!-- Other sentences -->
</corpus>
```

Comment: Incredibly simple and working as a charm! I didn't know lxml because i never parsed xml files in python before today. Thank you so much!